# Issue with Cascading Drop downs MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I have two drop downs on an form (plus other elements)

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label asp-for="job.LocationId"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <select asp-for="job.LocationId" id="LocationId" name="LocationId" 
                    asp-items="@Model.LocationList" class="form-select">
                <option disabled selected>--Select Location--</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label asp-for="job.RoomId"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <select id="RoomId" name="RoomId" asp-for="job.RoomId" 
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"))" class="form-select">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

a Change in locationId should change the values in RoomId.

I have this Java script

```
   

     <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#LocationId').change(function () {
                $("#RoomId").empty();  
                    $.ajax({  
                        type: 'GET',  
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetRooms")', // we are calling json method   
                        dataType: 'json',   
                        data: { locationId: $('#LocationId Option:Selected').val() },   
                   // here we are get value of selected country and passing same value as inputto json method GetStates.  
       
                    success: function (rooms) {  
                        // states contains the JSON formatted list  
                        // of states passed from the controller  
                        
                        $.each(rooms, function (i, room) {  
                        $("#RoomId").append('<option value="' + room.Value  + '">' +    
                             room.Text  + '</option>');                        
                        // here we are adding option for States    
                        });  
                    },  
                    error: function (ex) {  
                        alert('Failed to retrieve rooms.' + ex);  
                    }  
                });  
                return false;  
        })
    });
    </script>
```

which calls this code in the controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetRooms(string locationId)
        {
            int.TryParse(locationId, out int LocID);
            
            List<SelectListItem> rooms = new List<SelectListItem>();
            rooms.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-- Select Room --", Value = "0" });
            IEnumerable<Room> roomList = _unitOfWork.Room.GetAll(r => r.LocationId == LocID);
            foreach (Room room in roomList)
            {
                rooms.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = room.RoomName, Value = room.Id.ToString() });
            }


            //roomList.Insert(0, new Room { Id = 0, LocationId = LocID, RoomName = "-- Select Room --", RoomVolume =0 });
            var list = Json(new SelectList(rooms, "Value", "Text"));
            return Json(new SelectList(rooms, "Value", "Text"));
        }
```

which all works I get back the number of elements I expect in the drop down (3) but they all say undefined. I can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response data is camel case format, so you need change the code below:

```
$("#RoomId").append('<option value="' + room.value  + '">' +    
                             room.text  + '</option>');                        
                        // here we are adding option for States    
                        });
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so obvious really.